# cvBlobsLib external link error..please help me

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, cvblobslib

today I've compiled "cvblobslib" for Windows with OpenCV in my Visual Studio C++ 2010.

Compilation goes OK, and I obtain "cvblobslib.lib".

I've follow the istruction on library to set Visual C++ in my project to use this library (C++ additional directories and other) like in the instructions, that I quote here:

"1 - open the project of the library and build it (OK, done)
2 - in the project where the library should be used, add:

2.1 In "Project/Settings/C++/Preprocessor/Additional Include
directories" add the directory where the blob library is stored (done)

2.2 In "Project/Settings/Link/Input/Additional library path" add
the directory where the blob library is stored and in "Object/Library
modules" add the cvblobslib.lib file (where? In the visual studio folder or in my project folder?)

3- Include the file "BlobResult.h" where you want to use blob variables (OK, done)

NOTE: Verify that in the project where the cvblobslib.lib is used, the MFC Runtime Libraries are not mixed:

1. Check in "Project->Settings->C/C++->Code Generation->Use run-time library" of your project and set it to
   Debug Multithreaded DLL (debug version ) or to Multithreaded DLL ( release version ).
   2 Check in "Project->Settings->General" how it uses the MFC. It should be "Use MFC in a shared DLL". (done)

Can anyones help me, because with this code:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv\cxcore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

// Main blob library include
#include "BlobResult.h"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{

CBlobResult blobs;
int i;
CBlob *currentBlob;
IplImage *original,*originalThr,*displayedImage;

//carica immagine
original = cvLoadImage("pic6.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cvThreshold(original,originalThr,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);

//cerca le blob non bianche
blobs = CBlobResult(originalThr,NULL,255);

//le esclude quelle più piccole del parametro 2
blobs.Filter(blobs, B_EXCLUDE, CBlobGetArea(), B_LESS, 80);

//prende le parti grigie delle blob più grandi
CBlob biggestBlob;
CBlobGetMean getMeanColor(original);
double meanGray;

blobs.GetNthBlob(CBlobGetArea(), 0, biggestBlob);
meanGray = getMeanColor(biggestBlob);

//display it
cvMerge(originalThr,originalThr,originalThr,NULL, displayedImage);

for(i=0; i<blobs.GetNumBlobs();i++)
{
    currentBlob = blobs.GetBlob(i);
    currentBlob->FillBlob(displayedImage, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
}

return 0;

}
```

I obtain this errors:

```
1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: prova64, Configurazione: Debug x64 ------
1>Compilazione avviata 13/09/2013 15:31:44.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Aggiornamento timestamp di "x64\Debug\prova64.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Tutti gli output sono aggiornati.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  Tutti gli output sono aggiornati.
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __cdecl CBlob::~CBlob(void)" (??1CBlob@@QEAA@XZ) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: void __cdecl CBlob::FillBlob(struct _IplImage *,struct CvScalar,int,int)" (?FillBlob@CBlob@@QEAAXPEAU_IplImage@@UCvScalar@@HH@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: class CBlob * __cdecl CBlobResult::GetBlob(int)" (?GetBlob@CBlobResult@@QEAAPEAVCBlob@@H@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: void __cdecl CBlobResult::GetNthBlob(class COperadorBlob *,int,class CBlob &)const " (?GetNthBlob@CBlobResult@@QEBAXPEAVCOperadorBlob@@HAEAVCBlob@@@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __cdecl CBlob::CBlob(void)" (??0CBlob@@QEAA@XZ) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: void __cdecl CBlobResult::Filter(class CBlobResult &,int,class COperadorBlob *,int,double,double)" (?Filter@CBlobResult@@QEAAXAEAV1@HPEAVCOperadorBlob@@HNN@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: virtual __cdecl CBlobResult::~CBlobResult(void)" (??1CBlobResult@@UEAA@XZ) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: class CBlobResult & __cdecl CBlobResult::operator=(class CBlobResult const &)" (??4CBlobResult@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __cdecl CBlobResult::CBlobResult(struct _IplImage *,struct _IplImage *,unsigned char)" (??0CBlobResult@@QEAA@PEAU_IplImage@@0E@Z) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: __cdecl CBlobResult::CBlobResult(void)" (??0CBlobResult@@QEAA@XZ) non risolto nella funzione main
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: double __cdecl CBlob::Mean(struct _IplImage *)" (?Mean@CBlob@@QEAANPEAU_IplImage@@@Z) non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual double __cdecl CBlobGetMean::operator()(class CBlob &)" (??RCBlobGetMean@@UEAANAEAVCBlob@@@Z)
1>testeblob.obj : error LNK2019: riferimento al simbolo esterno "public: double __cdecl CBlob::Area(void)" (?Area@CBlob@@QEAANXZ) non risolto nella funzione "public: virtual double __cdecl CBlobGetArea::operator()(class CBlob &)" (??RCBlobGetArea@@UEAANAEAVCBlob@@@Z)
1>C:\OPENCV\Test\Elabora64\prova64\x64\Debug\prova64.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 12 esterni non risolti
1>
1>Compilazione NON RIUSCITA.
1>
1>Tempo trascorso 00:00:00.81
========== Compilazione: 0 completate, 1 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========
```

Why I obtain "external link error" ??

Please, help me...I don't know what to do...

Comment: Did you add the library file name to linker->input->additional dependencies in visual studio?

Comment: yes...but same problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly set the path to the **64-bit** cvblobslib.lib.

Go to Project Settings, Configuration Properties and find the settings:

- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories
- Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

Although, this is easier if the cvblobslib project is in the same solution as prova64, in which case you can add a project reference (right click prova64 project, References..., add the cvblobslib project).

Comment: the problem persist. I have setted correct directory e library path...but the problem still remain...why?? I'm on visual c++ 2010 professional and win7 64bit on 64bit programs...why even I put te correct parameters, don't work???

Comment: Make sure you built a 64 bit cvblobslib?

Comment: I use a pre-build ones...(1,13mb) and after, I build my own with the project vc++ included in archive of cvblobs...I don't read in any guide that it's possibile make a 32bit or 64bit...but only a release or debug version (I made debug version)...

Comment: That's probably your problem then.  You are building a 64-bit project, so you need to link against the 64-bit lib.

Comment: YEAH!!! I have recompiled the library in a x64 project, and works!! No more linker errors!! Thank you very much!!